# Should phone/email(varchar) be store as null or default blank?(InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, database

If someone does not have a phone or does not want to input his/her phone number, should the value store in DB be default blank or null?

Suppose if a person A is dealing with the service person B directly without using a website, thus person A does not want to give his/her email as may not have one.

Comment: Its based on your DB Engine

Comment: could you please clarify what do you mean?

Comment: If the column is going to be optional it should be NULL, NULL means no data, a blank in a column means empty but not null.

Comment: @JOnathaFlint If your are using InnoDB engine means set default as NULL or leave it empty

Comment: then when is NULL not appropriate to be used...I read many posts about why null is "bad/good" something and it kind of confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is optional it should be `NULL` as default, because it could have a value or not, when you set a blank `''`  it has a value, empty value, but still value.

One big pro of using `NULL` as default is if you sort by the column, `NULL` values will be displayed first.

In case the value is not optional, blank (`''`) *could* be a valid default value, but in general makes no sense, because a non-optional column normally should be filled with some data.